# Word says macros are disabled but settings show they are enabled

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2007

I use Word 2007. I have a Word template that has an AutoNew macro. That macro sets a few document variables and then calls a macro in Normal.dot to do the real work. This was developed in WordBasic (Word 6.0).

Suddenly it doesn't work anymore...

```
Public Sub MAIN()
    ' This is an Auto-numbering document.
    '
    WordBasic.SetDocumentVar "DocType", "brf"   'communicate document type
    WordBasic.SetDocumentVar "DocLang", "e"     'communicate document language
    '
    WordBasic.Call "AutoNumDoc"                 ' <-- doesn't work anymore
End Sub
```

It still worked on 5/17/2017. Macros are enabled. What has changed? Any suggestions?

---

Update: Actually it complains that

> macros in this project are disabled

but WordOptions -> Trust Center -> Macro Options says they are enabled.

Comment: You must be really upset, considering the typos in the original of this message... I take it AutoNumDoc is supposed to be in Normal.dotm? Is this a Normal.dotm or a Normal.dot? Has it been moved at any point? Is the folder in which it's stored no longer trusted? Is it possible company IT policy has done something to change the trust settings of that folder? What does this code look like? Are you able to create a test macro in Normal.dot(m) and call that from another document?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the WordBasic.Call instruction.

The hint was that macros were disbled, even though the Word settings said the were enabled.

The cause is that I moved my templates to a new location so they would be backed-up, but didn't add that path to the **Trusted Locations** of the **Trust Center**.